# How to wrap selected code with user defined text before and after the selection

Tags: eclipse, code-folding

In eclipse, I'd like to select a section of code with my mouse and then hit some sort of keyboard shortcut that causes the selection to be surrounded like so:

```
// [region]
public void someFunction() {
    ...
}
// [endregion]
```

Where the code is surrounded by the (user defined) comment lines "// [region]" and "// [endregion]" How would I do this? In netbeans, you can do something similar as referenced here: http://wiki.netbeans.org/SurroundWithCodeFolding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can cover a single or block of statements with if, do, for, while etc etc.

Select a single or block of statements then press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>

You will see the below popup. Choose the appropriate option. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

But you asking to cover a set of statements with method, for this you have to refractor the code.

Select a single or block of statements then press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>

Then a dialog will appear, fill up the details and click on OK button.

Comment: Ok I was able to figure it out from your post. I created a new template called "Region" with the following contents: 
    // [region]
    ${line_selection}${cursor}
    // [end region]